# How to do jquery canvas gradient for jquery knob?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

Here is the design which i am try to achieve using canvas:

[image]

I have to get the gradient in the radius of the circle with some inner shadow along the edges.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/77704ydb/4/)

I have very minimum knowledge with canvas, so any help will be much appreciated.

I am using the jquery knob plugin to show the progress bar: [JQUERY-KNOB](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)

HTML

```
<div class="demo">
  <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left:100px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input class="knob" data-width="100%" value="45">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
        $(function ($) {

        $(".knob").knob({
            class: 'group-canvas',
            change: function (value) {
                //console.log("change : " + value);
            },
            release: function (value) {
                //console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                console.log("release : " + value);
            },
            cancel: function () {
                console.log("cancel : ", this);
            },
            /*format : function (value) {
                return value + '%';
            },*/
            draw: function () {

                // "tron" case
                if (this.$.data('skin') == 'tron') {

                    this.cursorExt = 0.3;

                    var a = this.arc(this.cv) // Arc
                    ,
                        pa // Previous arc
                        ,
                        r = 1;

                    this.g.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;

                    if (this.o.displayPrevious) {
                        pa = this.arc(this.v);
                        this.g.beginPath();
                        this.g.strokeStyle = this.pColor;
                        this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, pa.s, pa.e, pa.d);
                        this.g.stroke();
                    }

                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = r ? this.o.fgColor : this.fgColor;
                    this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth, a.s, a.e, a.d);
                    this.g.stroke();

                    this.g.lineWidth = 2;
                    this.g.beginPath();
                    this.g.strokeStyle = this.o.fgColor;
                    this.g.arc(this.xy, this.xy, this.radius - this.lineWidth + 1 + this.lineWidth * 2 / 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                    this.g.stroke();

                    return false;
                }
            }
        });


        // Example of infinite knob, iPod click wheel
        var v, up = 0,
            down = 0,
            i = 0,
            $idir = $("div.idir"),
            $ival = $("div.ival"),
            incr = function () {
                i++;
                $idir.show().html("+").fadeOut();
                $ival.html(i);
            },
            decr = function () {
                i--;
                $idir.show().html("-").fadeOut();
                $ival.html(i);
            };

    });
```

CSS

```
.group-canvas {

width: 20vh !important;

height: 20vh !important;

}

.knob {

margin-top: 14vh !important;

width: 24vh !important;

height: 13vh !important;

font-size: 9vh !important;

margin-left: -32vh !important;

}
```

and this is what i have managed to achieve so far with the above code and changing the fgColor in the http://anthonyterrien.com/js/jquery.knob.js file ( i know i should not be editing this file, but just as a trial i have changed the fgColor)  :

```
fgColor: this.$.data('fgcolor') || '#dd3002',
```

[image]

Comment: I posted a good starting point for you. It's late night here so it's a bit rough--but a good start. Good Night!

Comment: Thank you mark, much appreciated. I will have a look.

Answer (score 2):

*Here's a starting point for you:* **This is a gradient arc with 3D-ish shadowing.**

[image]

**You can draw a gradient arc like this:**

```
function drawGradientArc(cx,cy,r, startAngle,endAngle, startColor,endColor, strokewidth) {
    var sweep=endAngle-startAngle;       
    var xStart = cx + Math.cos(startAngle) * r;
    var xEnd = cx + Math.cos(startAngle + sweep) * r;
    var yStart = cy + Math.sin(startAngle) * r;
    var yEnd = cy + Math.sin(startAngle + sweep) * r;
    //
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, startColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, endColor);
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, startAngle, startAngle + sweep);
    ctx.lineWidth = strokewidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

**You can draw an arc with 3D-ish shadows like this:**

```
function drawShadow(cx,cy,r,strokewidth){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle='white';
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.shadowColor='black';
    ctx.shadowBlur=15;
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-5,0,PI*2);
    ctx.clip();
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,0,PI*2);
    ctx.stroke();
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-strokewidth,0,PI*2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-strokewidth,0,PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle='white'
    ctx.fill();
    //
    ctx.restore();
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var PI=Math.PI;
var startColor='#DD3002';
var endColor='#FF9966';

drawGradientArc(150,150,93, -PI/4,Math.PI/4, startColor,endColor,43);

drawShadow(150,150,120,50);

ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.font='40px verdana';
ctx.fillStyle=startColor;
ctx.fillText('25%',150,150);

function drawShadow(cx,cy,r,strokewidth){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.strokeStyle='white';
  ctx.lineWidth=5;
  ctx.shadowColor='black';
  ctx.shadowBlur=15;
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-5,0,PI*2);
  ctx.clip();
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,0,PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-strokewidth,0,PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,r-strokewidth,0,PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='white'
  ctx.fill();
  //
  ctx.restore();
}

function drawGradientArc(cx,cy,r, startAngle,endAngle, startColor,endColor, strokewidth) {
  var sweep=endAngle-startAngle;       
  var xStart = cx + Math.cos(startAngle) * r;
  var xEnd = cx + Math.cos(startAngle + sweep) * r;
  var yStart = cy + Math.sin(startAngle) * r;
  var yEnd = cy + Math.sin(startAngle + sweep) * r;
  //
  var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, startColor);
  gradient.addColorStop(1.0, endColor);
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, startAngle, startAngle + sweep);
  ctx.lineWidth = strokewidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Mark, i would like this to be done using jquery knob plugin. This must be completely responsive on all device and jquery knob does that easily. Also the arch must be divided into 8 parts in the circle. each gradient filled part is 1 arch, so we should have 8 arc.

Comment: Cool--glad I could help! Your next steps are to (#1) pull the data-binding, UI & animation logic from jQuery-Knob and (#2) use my gradient-3D arc code as styling.  BTW, after you've combined #1 & #2 into your desired library, it's really quite simple to turn your library into a Query plugin. Simple as this: `$.fn.KnobByDexter=function(){...}` Good luck with your project. :-)